# Lazyload jquery plugin fails to load

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload

I have page where lazyload is loading more than 1000 images on scroll, if my browser "lags" (think of not smooth scrolling but it tackles), lazyload fails to execute on about 7 images after it loads first one in row. (8 images per row).

also happens if I'm scrolling too fast. (I think reason is the same as in above described situation)

I'm trying to figure out solution for this.

```
function lazyLoading() {
    jQuery("img.lazyload").lazyload({
        threshold : -10,
        failure_limit : 16,
        skip_invisible : false
    });
}
```

here is original function, I tried to modify it with .each() loop which results in just loading images in a regular way, just slower.

plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
I'm using responsive design, maybe that is cause?

it appears it is only webkit issue (chrome, safari) works very good on mozilla
also it appers it is only OS X issue. everything good on windows webkit browsers